# Can't install elementary-tweaks on Juno

Tags: release-juno, apt, thirdpartyapps

I'm trying to install elementary-tweaks on Juno but adding the ppa is causing an error. Here is my console output...

```
Err:7 http://ppa.launchpad.net/philip.scott/elementary-tweaks/ubuntu bionic InRelease                                                                  
The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY C1D89326B1C71AB9
Get:10 http://packages.elementary.io/appcenter bionic/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [88.5 kB]
Hit:11 https://packages.lunarg.com/vulkan/1.1.85 bionic InRelease 
Reading package lists... Done                                           
W: GPG error: http://ppa.launchpad.net/philip.scott/elementary-tweaks/ubuntu bionic InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY C1D89326B1C71AB9
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/philip.scott/elementary-tweaks/ubuntu bionic InRelease' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

Anyone know how I go about fixing this ? Thank you.

Comment: I had the same problem. @Sebastian's answer resolved the issue for me ️ ️

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Follow this steps

Open a terminal, then write and execute (by pressing <kbd>ENTER</kbd>) this commands, one at a time:

- `sudo apt install software-properties-common`

  - *will ask your password*
- `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:philip.scott/elementary-tweaks`

  - *will ask you press <kbd>ENTER</kbd> to confirm the installation of the PPA*
  - *(newer version of `add-apt-repository` runs `apt update` after automatically. In case it didn't, just run `sudo apt update` yourself)*
- `sudo apt install elementary-tweaks`

---

**Description of your problem:**

You didn't (don't) have the gpg key, with `add-apt-repository` you get it. And installing `software-properties-common` provides that command.

---

I'm curious, which instructions did you follow to install `elementary-tweaks`?

Comment: Hi. Well I'm sure I used those same command lines cribbed from another post. When I added the ppa there was a long delay and then an error was output, which I didn't grab unfortunately. Going through those three lines again has worked, thank you.