# Change default font Elementary OS Juno

Tags: fonts

I found some similar post but not fully satisfied with answers and not fully related to this question.

Default font in elementary OS is **Dejavu Sans** by command **`fc-match`**

Output in EOS : `$ fc-match`

`DejaVuSans.ttf: "DejaVu Sans" "Book"`

Output for this script :

```
for family in serif sans-serif monospace Arial Helvetica Verdana "Times New Roman" "Courier New"; do
  echo -n "$family: "
  fc-match "$family"
done
```

Is this :

```
serif: DejaVuSerif.ttf: "DejaVu Serif" "Book"
sans-serif: Arimo-Regular.ttf: "Arimo" "Regular"
monospace: Cousine-Regular.ttf: "Cousine" "Regular"
Arial: Arimo-Regular.ttf: "Arimo" "Regular"
Helvetica: Arimo-Regular.ttf: "Arimo" "Regular"
Verdana: DejaVuSans.ttf: "DejaVu Sans" "Book"
Times New Roman: Tinos-Regular.ttf: "Tinos" "Regular"
Courier New: Cousine-Regular.ttf: "Cousine" "Regular"
```

This font applied to all languages in Elementary OS system
Example scenario :

When you install Firefox or Chromium you will find that browser default font choose Dejavu Sans and compare this scenario in windows system that choose **Segoe UI**.

As other apps can show you too, that for ENG and other languages like Germany and Japanese and Persian or Arabic Dejavu Sans is chosen.

**I want to change fc-match font in Elementary OS**

This help me to change font for all language and choose a better replace font.

Feedback for EOS Dev team :

Please consider another font for Elementary OS than Dejavu Sans for System Fonts

Answer (score 0):

I have the same output of the `fc-match` command but my default font is different - changed by me using graphical interface provided by elementary tweaks. It is a third party package which gives additional options into system settings. See the accepted answer there how to install it - https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/a/17240/12483

Comment: I known about elementary tweak and changed in there
fc-match not change by elementary tweak
elementary tweak is set on Roboto for mine but still fc-match print Dejavu

Comment: But I don't understand what the problem is? As I wrote before, I have the same output of fc-match command like you, but If I change the default font using elementary-tweaks, the font of all applications is changed to the ones I choose there.  What do you want to achieve? To change the default fonts or the output of the  fc-match  command?

Comment: porbably this andswer will help you - https://superuser.com/a/1095575/245162

Comment: Want to change fonts for non English fonts 
Arabic - Persian - Japanese  and others
English fonts are good now and changed in that tool you said 
for other languages elementary tweak not work